# Is it theoretically possible to control or modify the probability of finding an electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-teleportation

We know that according to Quantum physics , electrons are not just regular particles with discrete location, and they kind of occupy all the space which has the ‘ highest probability ‘.

We can also say that for an electron at the origin, the ***probability of finding it at a distance of 10 metres from the origin is non-zero.***
All I am saying is , is there a way in which we could modify the electron ‘wave’ such that the probability of finding it suddenly becomes maximum at this new point P(10,0) ?

**Do we have any understanding of why and how does a single electron manage to form a ‘cloud’** and can we use that knowledge to “control” such a particle:  causing them to **teleport to a location of our wish.**

Comment: Teleportation of particle states is (as far as we know) not possible in the sense you describe. So called quantum teleportation transfers the state of one system to another system, this process needs classical and quantum communication channels. To make the particle have the maximum at some other point there is a simple way: just move it there (for example with electric fields in the case of an electron). This of course takes time (and the time is bounded from below by special relativity).

Comment: I get that. What I am trying to convey: I dont have words for it. Its like , if there could be a way to tap into the “internal properties” of the quantum particle and see “what” is causing the single electron to literally teleport around like crazy. Then possibly we could modify it to suit to our needs

Comment: When you apply power to the heater electrode of a vacuum tube, you increase the probability of finding an electron in the space around it. When you bias another electrode negative you increase the probability of those electrons moving to the anode.

Comment: Yup I realize that. But do we have any clue as to why particle behave the way they do? What causes it to have probablistic clouds rather than discrete positions; what causes it to teleport and entangle in such a bizarre way?

Comment: There is no answer to that question! It is just the best model for the way particles behave we have yet found! "why" questions are not something physics (or science in general) can answer absolutely, only with reference to our currently accepted models.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we absolutely have the technology to manipulate the position of a quantum particle. If you push the particle, you will increase the chance for it to be found on the other side of the room. For example, I just tossed a can in the trash, thereby manipulating the state of billions of billions of quantum particles with high precision.

This is a bit tongue in check. Point is, all particles are quantum particles. What you’re asking for is not nearly as spooky as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

> can we use that knowledge to “control” such a particle: causing them to teleport to a location of our wish.

We don't know "why" they behave the way they do, but we do know quite a bit about how they behave, and what factors determine how they move.

> is there a way in which we could modify the electron ‘wave’ such that the probability of finding it suddenly becomes maximum at this new point P(10,0) ?

There's no practical way known to make an electron "teleport" 10 m.

But we can set up conditions where they will teleport or *tunnel* by a few nanometers.

For example, in an [Esaki diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_diode) this effect is used to produce a negative differential resistance device useful for building high frequency oscillators.

In a  [scanning tunneling microscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_tunneling_microscope) the effect is used to image atomic-scale structures.